Выборка из базы данных, получить необходимый порядок
WHERE ID IN(5,10,33,1)

Когда выполняем подобную выборку,на выходе получаем записи в том порядке в котором они расположены в таблице.
Как выполнить так, чтобы на выходе получить записи именно в том порядке в котором указаны в  IN() ??

Попробовать отсортировать через case when. Без точного указания сортировки, бд будет выводить записи, как захочет

https://stackoverflow.com/a/396771/5045688

Нужно описать порядок вывода, например во временной таблице:
#Основная таблица
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    user text
);

#Таблица определяющая порядок вывода
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE order_table (
    order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT
);

# ВВод основной таблицы
INSERT INTO users (id, user) values
(1,  'Максим'),
(2,  'Михаил'),
(3,  'Александр'),
(4,  'Дмитрий'),
(5,  'Денис'),
(6,  'Илья'),
(7,  'Андрей'),
(8,  'Даниил'),
(9,  'Артём'),
(10, 'Иван'),
(11, 'Алексей'),
(12, 'Никита'),
(13, 'Павел'),
(14, 'Евгений'),
(15, 'Антон'),
(16, 'Лев'),
(17, 'Эльдар'),
(18, 'Григорий'),
(19, 'Владимир'),
(20, 'Руслан');

#Заполнить таблицу соответсвия
INSERT INTO order_table (order_id, user_id) VALUES
(1, 8),
(2, 13),
(3, 5),
(4, 10),
(5, 31);


SELECT 'Через левое соединение' as '1';
SELECT t1.user_id, ifnull(t2.user, 'Не определен' ) users
FROM order_table t1 left join users t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id;

SELECT 'Через внутреннеe соединение' as '2';
SELECT t1.user_id, t2.user users
FROM order_table t1 inner join users t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id;


+--------------------------------------------+
| 1                                          |
+--------------------------------------------+
| Через левое соединение                     |
+--------------------------------------------+
+---------+-------------------------+
| user_id | users                   |
+---------+-------------------------+
|       8 | Даниил                  |
|      13 | Павел                   |
|       5 | Денис                   |
|      10 | Иван                    |
|      31 | Не определен            |
+---------+-------------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Через внутреннеe соединение                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
+---------+--------------+
| user_id | users        |
+---------+--------------+
|       8 | Даниил       |
|      13 | Павел        |
|       5 | Денис        |
|      10 | Иван         |
+---------+--------------+


Используйте INNER JOIN, если:

Вам нужны только строки, которые имеют соответствия в обеих таблицах.
Вы хотите оптимизировать производительность запроса.

Используйте LEFT JOIN, если:

Вам нужны все строки из левой таблицы, даже если нет соответствий в правой таблице.
Вы хотите сохранить информацию из левой таблицы, даже если нет соответствий в правой таблице.
https://onecompiler.com/mysql/42y9jkcmw

А можно полюбопытствовать, почему именно LEFT, а не INNER?

@Akina как-то автоматически, хотел вывести все значения которые во временной таблице, но готов услышать замечания, я не очень силен в этом, но иногда требуется использовать.

@Akina я правильно понимаю, что если точно известно что все записи во временной таблице существуют, то лучше использовать inner join, а если хочется узнать каких записей нет в основной таблице left join?

И да, и нет. При INNER JOIN выводятся только записи, присутствующие в обеих таблицах, верно. А вот при LEFT JOIN  записи, отсутствующие в основной, будут выведены как NULL-NULL. Чтобы получить все записи из таблицы порядка, и имена для тех записей, которые есть в таблице юзеров, выходной набор должен быть SELECT t1.user_id, t2.user ...

@Akina, Спасибо, оставлю для себя надеюсь автор не выпилится :)

Для действительно наглядности - добавьте в исходные данные в каждую таблицу по записи, которая отсутствует в другой таблице. Тогда разницу будет видно наглядно.
